# Any with singular count noun

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns, any

I've been having problems with the use of any, I've read that you can use it for negative and questions with non-counts and plural count nouns, but there is an exception that you can use any with singular count nouns and in affirmative referring to "whatever" but just in that case. However, I read in my book this: They didn't take any action against them.
So, my question is: Is this an exception?
I'm sorry I cannot provide more context, but you would really help if you answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can use it with count singulars in non-affirmative contexts, for example “I haven't got any job lined up for you today" / ”I don’t think any student completed the project on time”. It can also be used with count singulars in its ‘free choice’ sense, as in “Any policeman should be able to help you”.

Comment: Thank you so much, BillJ!